# Passing dynamic JSON data to create a HTML table

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I have a function that receives JSON data, it can be any length and contain any number of columns and rows of data.

I have read that jqGrid would be a good jQuery plugin to use for this scenario but I cannot get it to work.

I have the following code to try and get my table to be populated:

```
//This code is in another section of my web page but the data is valid 
//and is populated over a websocket
var ss = $.parseJSON(data);
var theGrid = jQuery("#list1")[0];
theGrid.addJSONData(ss.NewDataSet.SECURITY_GROUPS);
//alert(ss.NewDataSet.SECURITY_GROUPS[0].NAME);

$(document).ready(function() {
           jQuery("#list1").jqGrid({
            datatype: "local",
            height: 250,
            multiselect: true,
            caption: "Manipulating Array Data"
        });
         });

<table id="list1"></table>
```

Comment: Shouldn't `theGrid.addJSONData(ss.NewDataSet.SECURITY_GROUPS);` be in the document.ready ? Are you sure the data is not getting populated before jqGrid is initialized ?

Comment: No, I make the request to the page and document ready gets fired etc, then I click a button which then populates my JSON object. It is at this point I want to send this to a HTML table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe give [DataTables](http://datatables.net/) a try if jqGrid isn't working for you.  It's probably my favorite, and super easy to load via JSON as you've described.

Here's how to load from an AJAX source: http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/data_sources/ajax.html

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').dataTable( {
        "bProcessing": true,
        "sAjaxSource": '../ajax/sources/arrays.txt'
    });
});
```

**UPDATE**

```
var columnArr = [];
var valueArr = [];
var data = ss.NewDataSet.SECURITY_GROUPS; //data is your SECURITY_GROUPS object

//Strip the titles off your first array item only since they are all the same.
$.each(data[0], function(key, value) {
    columnArr.push({"sTitle" : key});
});

$.each(data, function(key, value) {
    var innerArr = [];
    $.each(value, function(innerKey, innerValue) {
        innerArr.push(innerValue);
    });
    valueArr.push(innerArr);
});

$('#example').dataTable( {
    "aaData": valueArr,
    "aoColumns": columnArr
});
```

Comment: But its not via AJAX and I also dont know the layout of the HTML table which I believe DataTables requires. I just want to throw a JSON object to it and let it draw

Comment: Check this one out: http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/data_sources/js_array.html  You can just bind it right to your object literal (note: JSON is by definition a string, not an object).  As far as I'm aware, it doesn't care how many columns or whatever you have, it'll manage just fine.  The only thing you'll need to do is strip out the column headers so it knows where those are, if you have any.

Comment: Here is my JSON. https://gist.github.com/1226807 The stuff I'm interested in is from line 103 onwards.  In that example you posted is there a way I can loop through the first set of data and draw the column names?

Comment: See my update.  I coded it blindly, so I don't promise a lack of bugs, but it should set you in the right direction.

Comment: You my friend are a legend. Thanks very much! Only one minor typo in your example

Comment: Its me specific but you said var data = ss.columnArr.NewDataSet.SECURITY_GROUPS; whereas it should be var data = ss.NewDataSet.SECURITY_GROUPS;